# Condicionar una clase css con vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estoy iniciando un ciclo FOR con vue, Necesito condicionar que si el index es igual a cero aparesca la clase "active" y si el index es mayor a cero que no aparesca la clase "active".

**De la linea que hablo es esta**

```
  <a v-if="index == 0" :class="{ 'nav-link active': true}" >
```

**CODIGO COMPLETO**

```
<a v-if="index == 0" :class="{ 'nav-link active': true}" > @{{item.clientes.nombre}} 
    @{{index}}  <span  v-on:click="confirmar_delete_espera(item.clientes)" class="">x</span></a>         

   </li>
  </template>
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo se renderiza con la clase active o directamente no se renderiza... entonces no necesitas condicionar la clase

Comment: necesito que aparesca con la clase active solo cuando el index es cero de resto los siguientes items se renderizan sin esa clase.  a ver si me entiendes

Comment: Edita la pregunta para ver mejor el código

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a v-if="index == 0" :class="{ 'nav-link active': true}" > @{{item.clientes.nombre}} 
    @{{index}}  <span  v-on:click="confirmar_delete_espera(item.clientes)" class="">x</span></a>
```

La directiva v-if te va a servir para condicionar si se renderiza el elemento completo, no creo que sea eso lo que necesitas. Para condicionar la clase tienes varias sintaxis, aunque creo que la más apropiada en tu caso es la de objeto...

Tu código quedaría algo así...

```
<li v-for="(item,index) in yourArray" :key=index>
    <a class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active': index === 0}" > @{{item.clientes.nombre}} 
            @{{index}}  
       <span  v-on:click="confirmar_delete_espera(item.clientes)" class="">x</span></a>
</li>
```

Si te fijas, el objeto contiene el nombre de la clase como clave (**active**) y si su valor devuelve `true` la clase se pintara en el elemento.

Espero que te sirva,

Saludos

Comment: Me sirve amigo, pero necesito que por cada iteracion me evalue tambien que si es mayor a cero, no se pinte la clase active, y quede solo "nav-link "

Comment: En el v-for pinta la clave.... la sintaxis es...

`<li v-for="(value,index) in list">`.... en el caso de que sea array tu lista...

si es objeto... 
`<li v-for="(value,key,index) in list">`

Answer (score 2):

Basado en la documentación de **Vue**

para enlazar clases

seria algo asi:

```html
<div v-bind:class="{ 'active': isActive }"></div>
```

En tu caso en particular sería algo asi:

```html
<a v-bind:class="{ 'active': item == 0}"></a>
```

Referencia: [Vue](https://es-vuejs.github.io/vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)